# Issue with local connection between 2 programs over TCP

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tcpclient, jetbrains-ide, tcplistener

So I have a really *really* weird issue. This is going to take a tiny bit of a wall to explain fully..

I'm running some game servers for a Unity game called SCP: Secret Laboratory, and have a custom-made C# Discord Bot that helps my staff moderate both in-game and on Discord, by controlling bans, logging player warnings, etc, etc.

I'm trying to make the two platforms communicate with each other over a TCP port over the local machine address (127.0.0.1).
I've setup the listener on the bot, to whom the individual servers (there are 7) will connect to when they are ready.

I've also set it up so that if the connection is broken from either side, the servers will close the TcpClient, start a new one, and attempt to connect, while the listener just resumes listening on that port for a connection again, after closing the client on it's side.

I've tested it several times by closing the client, the socket, or just rebooting the program on either end, and they seem to without fail reconnect flawlessly.

Here's my issue..

While the game servers remain empty, everything is fine. After players start to connect, anywhere from 5mins to an hour will go by, then suddenly, seemingly at random, the server no longer 'hears' the bot when it talks across the connection, however, the bot itself does not hit an error when trying to send data, the server just never receives any. What's stranger, is the server will **continue to send it's own data** over the connection, and the bot **does** receive that data.

To attempt to 'reset' the connection with a new client when this happens, I make the servers send an initial heartbeat to the bot when they first connect. This tells the bot that the connection is established on the server's end, and begins a looping thread that will send an AYT message to the server every 10s, to which the server must reply.
If the bot sends 3 AYT messages without getting a response back, it will close the TcpClient, and start listening for a new one.
At this time, the server detects the connection was closed, disposes of it's client, instantiates a new one, and tries to connect successfully. The bot then receives it's initial heartbeat, and starts the AYT timer for that client again, but the server **continues** to not receive them. Or any data whatsoever sent from the bot, even though the bot still receives data from the server during this time.

The only solution to fix the problem at that point, is to fully restart the game server, after which it will connect to the bot and work perfectly fine, until it.. just doesn't anymore.

For reference, pastebins of the code used are below.

The bot "listener" side

```
public class ProcessSTT
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, TcpClient> bag = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, TcpClient>();
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> heartbeats = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

    public static void SendData(string data, int port, ulong channel = 0)
    {
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            SerializedData.SerializedData serializedData =
                new SerializedData.SerializedData { Data = data, Port = port, Channel = channel };
            //Console.WriteLine($"Sending {serializedData.Data}");
            if (!bag.ContainsKey(port))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"STT: Bag does not contain {port}");
                return;
            }

            if (bag[port] != null && bag[port].Connected)
                formatter.Serialize(bag[port].GetStream(), serializedData);
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error - Bag {port} is null or not connected.");
                if (bag.TryRemove(port, out TcpClient client))
                    client.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"STT: Socket exception, removing..");
            KeyValuePair<int, TcpClient> thingything = default;
            foreach (var thing in bag)
                if (thing.Key == port)
                    thingything = thing;

            if (bag.TryRemove(thingything.Key, out TcpClient _client))
            {
                _client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }

    private static List<TcpListener> listener = new List<TcpListener>();
    public static void Init()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 8; i++)
        {
            TcpListener list = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Loopback, 11900 + i);
            Console.WriteLine($"STT: Listener started for port {11900 + i}");
            listener.Add(list);
            list.Start();
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ListenForConn, list);
        }
    }

    public static async Task Heartbeat(int port)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        for (;;)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("STT: Starting Heartbeat");
            if (heartbeats[port] > 3)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"STT: Removing {port} due to heartbeat timeout.");
                if (bag.TryRemove(port, out TcpClient client))
                    client.Close();
                heartbeats.TryRemove(port, out int _);
                return;
            }

            heartbeats[port]++;

            Console.WriteLine($"STT: Sending heartbeat to: {port}");
            if (!bag[port].Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"STT: {port} is null, removing.");
                if (bag.TryRemove(port, out TcpClient client))
                    client.Close();

                return;
            }
            SendData("ping", port, 653737934150959115);
            await Task.Delay(10000);
        }
    }

    public static void ListenForConn(object token)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("STT: Listener started.");
        TcpListener listen = token as TcpListener;
            for (;;)
            {
                try
                {
                    TcpClient thing = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ListenOn, thing);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
        }
    }

    public static async Task ReceiveData(SerializedData.SerializedData data, TcpClient client)
    {
        try
        {
            if (data == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("STT: Received data null");
                return;
            }

            if (data.Data == "ping")
            {
                if (!bag.ContainsKey(data.Port))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"STT: Adding {data.Port}");
                    bag.TryAdd(data.Port, client);
                }

                if (!bag[data.Port].Connected || bag[data.Port] == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"STT: Bag {data.Port} not connected or null, removing.");
                    if (bag.TryRemove(data.Port, out TcpClient cli))
                    {
                        cli?.Close();
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine($"STT: Received heartbeat for: {data.Port}");
                if (!heartbeats.ContainsKey(data.Port))
                {
                    Heartbeat(data.Port);
                    heartbeats.TryAdd(data.Port, 0);
                }
                else
                    heartbeats[data.Port]--;
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine(data.Data);
            data.Data = data.Data.Substring(data.Data.IndexOf('#') + 1);

            //Console.WriteLine("Getting guild.");
            SocketGuild guild = Bot.Discord.GetGuild(478381106798788639);
            //Console.WriteLine("Getting channel");
            SocketTextChannel chan = guild.GetTextChannel(data.Channel);
            //Console.WriteLine("Sending message.");
            await chan.SendMessageAsync($"Server {data.Port -= 7770}: {data.Data}");
            if (data.Port == 7771)
            {
                DiscordWebhookClient webhook = new DiscordWebhookClient(
                    "");
                await webhook.SendMessageAsync($"{data.Data}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }

    }

    public static void ListenOn(object token)
    {
        TcpClient client = token as TcpClient;
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            for (;;)
            {
                SerializedData.SerializedData serializedData;
                if (!client.Connected)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Client not connected..");
                    client.Close();
                    continue;
                }

                serializedData = formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream()) as SerializedData.SerializedData;
                new Thread(() => ReceiveData(serializedData, client)).Start()
            }
        }
        catch (SerializationException s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"STT: Serialization exception, removing..");
            KeyValuePair<int, TcpClient> thingything = default;
            foreach (var thing in bag)
                if (thing.Value == client)
                    thingything = thing;

            if (bag.TryRemove(thingything.Key, out TcpClient _client))
            {
                _client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
    }
}
```

The server "speaker" side

```
public class ProcessSTT
{
    private static TcpClient tcpClient;
    public static readonly ConcurrentQueue<SerializedData.SerializedData> dataQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<SerializedData.SerializedData>();
    private static Thread _init;
    private static bool _locked;
    public static void Init()
    {
        if (_locked)
            return;
        _locked = true;
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        try
        {
            Plugin.Log($"STT: Starting INIT.");
            tcpClient?.Close();
            tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            while (!tcpClient.Connected)
            {
                Plugin.Log($"STT: While loop start");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
                try
                {
                    tcpClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", ServerConsole.Port + 4130);
                }
                catch (SocketException)
                {
                    tcpClient.Client.Disconnect(false);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Plugin.Log($"STT: {e}");
                }
            }

            Thread thread = new Thread(ReceiveData);
            thread.Start();
            SendData("ping", 0);
            _locked = false;
        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {
            _init = new Thread(Init);
            _init.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServerConsole.AddLog(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void SendData(string data, ulong channel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!tcpClient.Connected)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tcp Client not connected!");

            SerializedData.SerializedData serializedData = new SerializedData.SerializedData
            {
                Data = data, Port = ServerConsole.Port, Channel = channel
            };
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(tcpClient.GetStream(), serializedData);
            ServerConsole.AddLog($"Sent {data}");
        }
        catch (IOException i)
        {
            _init = new Thread(Init);
            _init.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServerConsole.AddLog(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void ReceiveData()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!tcpClient.Connected)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Tcp Client not connected!");
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            for (;;)
            {
                SerializedData.SerializedData deserialize =
                    formatter.Deserialize(tcpClient.GetStream()) as SerializedData.SerializedData;
                if (deserialize == null)
                    continue;
                dataQueue.Enqueue(deserialize);
            }
        }
        catch (SerializationException s)
        {
            _init = new Thread(Init);
            _init.Start();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            _init = new Thread(Init);
            _init.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServerConsole.AddLog(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}

public class HandleQueue
{
    public static ulong channelid;
    public static void HandleQueuedItems()
    {
        while (ProcessSTT.dataQueue.TryDequeue(out SerializedData.SerializedData result))
        {
            string command = result.Data;
            Plugin.Log($"STT: Received {result.Data} for {result.Port}");
            if (result.Port != ServerConsole.Port)
                return;

            if (result.Data == "ping")
            {
                Plugin.Log("STT: BLART Heartbeat received.");
                ProcessSTT.SendData("ping", 0);
                return;
            }

            channelid = result.Channel;

            try
            {
                GameCore.Console.singleton.TypeCommand($"/{command}", new BlartSender());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ServerConsole.AddLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerator<float> Handle()
    {
        for (;;)
        {
            HandleQueuedItems();
            yield return Timing.WaitForSeconds(1f);
        }
    }
}

public class BlartSender : CommandSender
{
    public override void RaReply(string text, bool success, bool logToConsole, string overrideDisplay)
    {
        ProcessSTT.SendData($"{text}", HandleQueue.channelid);
    }

    public override void Print(string text)
    {
        ProcessSTT.SendData($"{text}", HandleQueue.channelid);
    }

    public override string SenderId => "BLART";
    public override string Nickname => "BLART";
    public override ulong Permissions => ServerStatic.GetPermissionsHandler().FullPerm;
    public override byte KickPower => Byte.MaxValue;
    public override bool FullPermissions => true;
}`
```

Comment: Are you aware that the method `ListenOn` calls the `async Task ReceiveData` without await/wait() within an endless (for) loop? in class `ProcessSTT` The ReceiveData is probably called too many times before the method is finished. You should fix that first. And please instead of linking pastebins, you should place the code here. (if you indend the code with 4 spaces, it will create a code-block)

Comment: Yes, because `serializedData = formatter.Deserialize(client.GetStream()) as SerializedData.SerializedData;` is a blocking call that stops the forloop from proceeding until it actually has data to deserialize, and if the bot receives data before the first receive data is complete, I don't necessarily want to wait until the first process is done, if, for example, I receive something that takes 0.5s to process, but receive two other things less than 0.25s apart from eachother and less than 0.5s after the first, the bot will just process each thing on it's own thread.

Comment: Since the problem isn't the bot not processing data from the server, but rather the server not receiving data from the bot, and the bot won't be doing anything that isn't thread-safe within ReceiveData. I don't see how this is an issue anyways.

Comment: Also I didn't want to paste the code here in fear it would create an unbearably long wall of text, if you prefer I can change that.

Comment: It would help us if you could remove as many elements from your code you can such that the unexpected behavior is still reproduced. Also, definitely do include anything that's necessary to reproduce that unexpected behavior.

Comment: I mean, other than removing code segments and replacing them with comments to detail what was happening there, there isn't really much *to* remove. 

The things necessary: Have an SCP:SL game server connecting to a listening discord bot over the loopback address. 
Have players connect to the server. Wait until the server randomly stops receiving data from the bot.  ???   profit?   I'm not sure what you want me to trim out of the code, or how to explain the problem any simpler.

Comment: The only common factor of the connection 'breaking' is that while the game server remains empty, it doesn't happen. But when it does happen, while players are connected, it happens at random intervals with no seemingly common 'trigger'. IE rounds ending, certain number of players, certain in-game events, etc

Comment: This may be unrelated but it seems like if an `IOException` is caught in `Init`, then `Init` becomes permanently locked, which would mean that if later an Exception occurs in `ReceiveData`, then no additional `ReceiveData` methods will ever be called.

Comment: Not related, since the server does successfully reconnect to the bot when it re-calls init from other means, but you would be correct on that I believe, I'll copy the _locked = false into the catch blocks aswell to make sure the method is unlocked if it hits an exception that would otherwise block it permanently.
Honestly surprised that hasn't been an issue at some point, but I don't think that'll affect the actual behaviour any.

Comment: I somehow missed the entire second half of your comment.. That makes sense about the ReceiveData exception issue, i'll see if this fix helps any. But it's weird that if I close the tcpclient on the bot side, the server still creates a new one to reconnect with, which would mean Init() is still being called and run properly, so I'm abit confused on that.

Comment: I can only assume `Handle` is still doing its thing whether or not there is a `ReceiveData` thread running. Consider logging a warning if `HandleQueuedItems` is called so many times in a row without any `ReceiveData` threads running during any of them.  Also, please consider including @Ruzihm in your replies so I get notified about them.

Comment: @Ruzihm I'll try that if adding the `_locked = false` into the catch blocks on `Init` doesn't work, then I'll get back to you, thanks for pointing those out.

Comment: @JoshRaymond It's also a race condition possibility that you're in `Init` in thread A, it creates thread B with `ReceiveData`, that hits an exception and tries to create thread C back to `Init`, and that sees that `_locked` is true all before `_locked` is set back to false in thread A.

Comment: @Ruzihm Is there a better way to do connection recovery that wouldn't have that kind of issue?

Comment: I found a tcp client [here](https://github.com/ygoe/AsyncTcpClient/blob/master/AsyncTcpClient/AsyncTcpClient.cs) that basically wrapped their Init in a loop, and the end of the body of the loop has an `await` on a task with another loop that lasts until the connection is closed.  See the `RunAsync` method.  Details on this client [here](https://github.com/ygoe/AsyncTcpClient)

Comment: I just realized something after having gotten a nap - my `Handle()` method is only ever called once. If it, or `HandleQueuedItems()` hits an exception, the server would completely stop handling incoming data.  :pepemoonka: